# CSS modification in the code

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am sorry this sound little stupid, but there is no one else to resolve my query for this, that's why I asked it here.

I have written the following code, which is showing tooltip when I hover on moving text-marquee. But currently the problem is the tooltip is coming in left side with a relative below position. However I want it to be different like, the tooltip should appear right above where I hover the text. Can someone please modify my CSS?

```
<!-- CSS Part Start -->
<style type="text/css">
#NT_copy {
background-color: #333333;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 13px;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
width: 300px;
left: 10px;
top: 20px;
padding: 4px;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
z-index: 20;
-moz-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 10px;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=87);
-moz-opacity: .87;
-khtml-opacity: .87;
opacity: .87;
}
</style>
<!-- CSS Part End -->

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.fn.tooltip= function(options) {
  this.each(function(){
    var settings = {
      tooltipcontentclass:"searchTipcontent",
      width:200,
      position:"absolute",
      zindex:100 
    };
    if(options) {
      jQuery.extend(settings, options);
    }
    jQuery(this).children("."+settings.tooltipcontentclass).hide();
    jQuery(this).hover(function() {
      var de = document.documentElement;
      var w = self.innerWidth || (de&&de.clientWidth) || document.body.clientWidth;
      var hasArea = w - jQuery.fn.getAbsoluteLeftObject(this);
      var clickElementy = jQuery.fn.getAbsoluteTopObject(this) - 3; //set y position
      var title="&nbsp;";
      jQuery("body").append("<div id='NT'><div id='NT_copy'><div >"+jQuery(this).children("."+settings.tooltipcontentclass).html()+"</div></div></div>");//right side
      var arrowOffset =  this.offsetWidth + 11;
      var clickElementx = jQuery.fn.getAbsoluteLeftObject(this) + arrowOffset;
      jQuery('#NT').css({left: clickElementx+"px", top: clickElementy+"px"});
      jQuery('#NT').css({width: settings.width+"px"});
      jQuery('#NT').css({position: settings.postion});
      jQuery('#NT').css("z-index",settings.zindex);
      jQuery('#NT').show();
    } ,
    function() {
      jQuery("#NT").remove();
  })

  });
}
jQuery.fn.getAbsoluteLeftObject=function(o) {
  // Get an object left position from the upper left viewport corner
  oLeft = o.offsetLeft            // Get left position from the parent object
  while(o.offsetParent!=null) {   // Parse the parent hierarchy up to the document element
    oParent = o.offsetParent    // Get parent object reference
    oLeft += oParent.offsetLeft // Add parent left position
    o = oParent
  }
  return oLeft
}

jQuery.fn.getAbsoluteTopObject=function (o) {
  // Get an object top position from the upper left viewport corner
  oTop = o.offsetTop            // Get top position from the parent object
  while(o.offsetParent!=null) { // Parse the parent hierarchy up to the document element
    oParent = o.offsetParent  // Get parent object reference
    oTop += oParent.offsetTop // Add parent top position
    o = oParent
  }
  return oTop
}
</script>

<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

<div id="fixedfooter">
<marquee class="smooth_m" behavior="scroll" direction="left" onmouseout="this.start()" onmouseover="this.stop()" scrollamount="3">
<div id="demo">
    <span style="color: #ff0000;" class="formInfo">
    <div class="mycontent" style="color: #000000;display:none;">
        test Successful for HTML Tooltip on marquee
    </div>
    <a href="#"></a>Testing HTML Tooltip on marquee using jQuery and css</span>
</div>
</marquee>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".formInfo").tooltip({
        tooltipcontentclass: "mycontent"
    })
});;
</script>
```

Comment: What you're wanting is a dynamic tooltip. Why don't you use one of the many available tooltip plugins? Maybe [this one](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.html)?

Comment: because no one provides the functionality, which I want. :(
I want tooltip to show when I mouse-over on the moving marquee, and it should hide, when I remove mouse from the news.

Comment: What functionality are you wanting? You want a tooltip to show next to the mouse, right? The problem (with this code) is that you're using `position: relative`, when you need to `position: absolute` and *put* the element where you want it. `position: relative` puts the element in the flow with the rest of the elements adjacent to it in the DOM.

Comment: And in your edit, this is a plain-jane *tooltip*. I don't see what is unique about that, unless you only want the tooltip to show if it's over the *text* in the marquee, in which case you should abandon `marquee` and manually scroll an element so you can detect it's position and whether the cursor is over that position or not.

Comment: earlier I wrote **position: absolute**, but then I changed it to **position: relative** as the tooltip was going off the page (was not visible). Here is the sample screenshot position:relative http://i.imgur.com/SWquB.jpg . I do not know much about this, and have to show this tomorrow. I am worrying how will I be able to do that.

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cKCJL/) of what you've posted. If you just want the tooltip to show if you cursor over the entire `marquee` element, all you need is a regular tooltip plugin. If you want to trigger it only over the text that's in the `marquee`, then determine where the cursor is in relation to the `window`, use `position: absolute`, and trigger it only on `mousemove` over `.formInfo`. Make it *simpler*.

Comment: Jared, in your first comment you told to use - http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.html, but there is one drawback in it. that when I remove mouse from the text the tooltip should not be displayed. Thanks a lot for helping me with the fiddle,I think I am not able to tell the exact thing. I am sorry. I want the tooltip to appear just above whatever text is going in marquee. Like a news marquee, there will be many texts and many html tooltips for them.

Comment: I've added a demo of a (much simpler) approach.

Comment: And I'm wondering if what you're describing may be more like this? http://jsfiddle.net/6jTd6/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oftentimes, when you get stuck, set things aside and start over, even if it's only as an exercise. You have to clear your mind and preferably start very simply.

I've created a very simple tooltip functionality that works the way I believe you're wanting it to. Note, I've only included what is necessary for the demo, so note except for the red text in the `marquee`, it's completely unstyled. Also note, the `position` function needs to account for the width of the page and the width of the tooltip, so it doesn't "scroll offscreen". I'll let you work that out as an exercise, though.

**HTML**

I've moved the `this.start()` and `this.stop()` for the `marquee` into the `mousemove` handlers. Additionally, I've put the `#tooltip` element in the `body`, since it needs to be `position: absolute` in the context of the `body` element, not within another element nested further down.

```
<div id="fixedfooter">
    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="3">
        <span id="marquee-text">
            Testing HTML Tooltip on marquee using jQuery and css
        </span>
    </marquee>
</div>
<div id="tooltip">
    Successful for HTML Tooltip on marquee
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#fixedfooter {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ff0000;
}
#marquee-text {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

**Javascript**

The `var $tooltip = $('#tooltip')` and the line below it are jQuery *caching*. If you repeatedly access an element, always try to cache it's reference, and not call it from the jQuery selector over and over; this is a big performance problem.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var $tooltip = $('#tooltip'),
        $marquee = $('#marquee-text');

    var show = function(e){
        $marquee.parent('marquee')[0].stop();
        position.call(this, e);
        $tooltip.show();
    };

    var hide = function(e){
        $marquee.parent('marquee')[0].start();
        $tooltip.hide();
    };

    var position = function(e){
        $tooltip.css({top: e.pageY + 20, left: e.pageX + 20});
    };

    $marquee
        .hover(show, hide)
        .mousemove(position);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6jTd6/

Comment: Hi Jared, thanks for your file. It works perfectly fine for the id. Can it also be changed to class. I tried changing # to . but then the tooltip loads in footer left only. I have updated the fiddle with the class content

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/6jTd6/1/ Things do change if you start doing things in series, instead of a single element like with an `id`. So the approach is going to be different if, say, you want to show more than one scroller with an associated tooltip, depending on the details.

Comment: I must say that you are a master in jquery and all. I was losing my hope, but you turned out the helper to me. One more thing, if you have little spare time, just like you provided me previous code, I modified **var position** to top: e.pageY - 55, and then the tooltip was exactly above the moving marquee. Can this be implemented in the latest fiddle code? thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/6jTd6/3/ Note, I just told the `.marquee-text` to be `position: relative` so I could then do `position: absolute` on the (child) `.tooltip` and put it at the "top" of the `.marquee-text` element. See it in series: http://jsfiddle.net/6jTd6/4/ You would `z-index` on `.tooltip` if you have more than one line: http://jsfiddle.net/6jTd6/5/

Comment: oops, i think my english is not so good. I mean to say that above the text (not replacing the text), like there is tooltip in this photo http://i.imgur.com/rS5Ka.png

Comment: You mean above, or on top of the text. That gets to be trickier, since what you really need to do is have the associated tooltip in the `body` context, since the very top tooltip will get cutoff if you try `top: "-" + ($this.outerHeight(true) + 5)`. Even a negative `margin-top` won't work, either. However, if it's going to be a fixed amount, you can add a `#marquees` element to wrap all of the scrolling text elements and add a `padding-top` to it so you can see the top tooltip: http://jsfiddle.net/6jTd6/8/ It's not the best solution, but it works in certain cases.

Comment: Note, my original fiddle I forgot to remove the reference to the `position` function when I removed it. Try: http://jsfiddle.net/6jTd6/8/

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. You are superb engineer.